# Sort column circular dependency was detected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to reorder the column order for a Matrix visualization.

So, I am trying to have "Less than 4 WorkDays" (SortWorkD = 1) as displayed far left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38rwK.png)
I already prepared a dataset that has the data of sort order ("1,2,3,4") matching with "WorkD" column shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd9ha.png)

when i try sort by column I get the message circular dependency was detected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Te7b.png)

any solutions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBy5H.png)

dependency was detected

Comment: you need to build the sorting column in Power Query, not in DAX.